# javascript window.open unspecified error

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a very simple javascript which launches a named window, so that I can close it later.

Most of the time this code works perfectly, but I've received reports of "unspecified error" messages on occasion. Once the message appears, it occurs every time this function is run until the system is restarted. This is occ

```
function openWin() {

  try{
      MsgWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MsgWindow','scrollbars=1,resizable=1',true);
  } 

  catch(e)   {InsertError(e.description);}
}
```

Comment: What browser(s) is this error appearing in?

Comment: Are you using IE for debugging? You might want to use another browser so as to get helpful rather than vague error messages.

Comment: I am using IE7 and unfortunately, I can't change that. I also can't force the error since it's seems to be completely random. I've tried installing IE8 and it still occurrs - completely randomly.

Answer (score 0):

`http:www.google.com` is nonsense. It should bw `http://www.google.com`.

Besides that, unless you need a global var `MsgWindow`, remove `MsgWindow=`.

Comment: Yeah, I just changed the URL for this purpose. I know the URL I have works correctly.

Comment: I'm following the function with: function closeWin() {try{MsgWindow.close();} catch(e){InsertError(e.description + '. CloseWin.');}}. Is there a better way to do this? I need to make sure that there is only 1 IE window open at any given time, so that I can close it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the final "true" parameter value for? window.open follows this API:

```
window.open(URL, windowName, windowFeatures);
```

You have a 4th parameter that shouldn't be there. Try this:

```
function openWin(url) {
    try{
        window.open(url, 'MsgWindow','scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
    } catch(e) {
        InsertError(e.description);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the replace parameter. I have removed it since it's not necessary, but I still have the issue.